# stripe connect not charging/transfering to connected users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Been struggling with this for a while, and can't seem to find a solid answer or tutorial:  My ruby application allows users to hire other users, and pay them within the app via their connected standalone account. I, as the platform owner, recieve a percentage as a service fee.  I have a "Pay now" button on their profile.  it brings up the payment form, and submits it.  At this point I get an error:

> uninitialized constant ChargesController::CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID

I've been told to replace that with a users "acct_xxxxxx" (stripe account id), but this is where I get confused, as I'm very new to this Stripe stuff.  I dont want just one user to always get paid.. so why would I put a single users acct in my controller? isn't that value supposed to be called from the db depending on the user? I really need someone to help me out here.  Every answer I get just confuses me more.  In my database, this value is saved as "

> UID

I follow tutorials exactly and get nowhere. Here's what I have so far:

charges_controller.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

def create
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_MMD##############"

Stripe::Account.retrieve(CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID)

token = params[:stripeToken]

# Create a customer
Stripe::Customer.create(
  {:description => "example@stripe.com"},
  {:stripe_account => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
)
# Create a Charge:
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  :amount => 1000,
  :currency => "cad",
  :source => token,
  :application_fee => 200 # amount in cents
}, :stripe_account => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}")

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
end
```

views/charges/new.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_CcUZ############');

$(function() {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  $form.submit(function(event) {
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

    // Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from being submitted:
    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) { // Problem!

    // Show the errors on the form:
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;

    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
</script>
```

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'],
  :stripe_account => ENV['UID']
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

application.yml

```
  PUBLISHABLE_KEY: pk_test_CcUZ#############
  STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: sk_test_MMDc############
  STRIPE_CLIENT_ID: ca_9nro7##############
```

assets/javascript/stripe.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_CcUZ############');
</script>
```

views/users/show.html.erb - Pay Now button.

```
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="Payment"
          data-amount="1000"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
```

Any suggestions on the above? to recap:
How do I correctly call the users stripe account id (UID)?
What is wrong in the above files which keeps the application from transferring funds to the correct users account?

Answer (score 0):

When you [create a destination charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges), you can only specify a single destination account.

If you need to pay multiple sellers, you'll either need to create multiple destination charges or use the "separate charges & transfers" flow described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers).